# Jackson annotation @JsonUnwrapped ignores @JsonProperty value

Tags: jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

Here's very simple scenario in which I got value object that I want to un-wrap for serialization. Using custom Serializer is not an option.

```
public class UnwrappedWithPropertyName {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        final Address address = new Address(new Postcode("45678"));

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(address));
    }


    static class Address {

        @JsonUnwrapped
        @JsonProperty("postcode")
        private final Postcode postcode;

        Address(Postcode postcode) {
            this.postcode = postcode;
        }

        public Postcode getPostcode() {
            return postcode;
        }
    }

    static class Postcode {

        private final String value;

        Postcode(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

That will result in

```
{"value":"45678"}
```

and what I would expect is

```
{"postcode":"45678"}
```

Answer (score 1):

By annotating field with @JsonValue one can control the name of such field from enclosing class.

```
static class Address {

    @JsonProperty("postcode")
    private final Postcode postcode;

    Address(Postcode postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public Postcode getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }
}

static class Postcode {

    @JsonValue
    private final String value;

    Postcode(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `@JsonProperty("postcode")` to `private final String value;`

Comment: it's not an option either. i want to use that Postcode class on other object and want parent to control the name of property. for one API I want postcode to be `zip` for other `post_code`. Putting that annotation on `Postcode` class will result in exporting always as `postcode`